# Ticking/Accepting own question

Tags: feature-request

The questioner chooses what he considers answers his/her question with a tick. In my opinion, though the option of answering ones own question is good, because it allows for clarifications and new thought, the possibility of [choosing your own answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/does-godel-preclude-a-workable-toe) as the best, seems to me, defeats the purpose of the question and answer forum.

Particularly when the chosen answer is being only down voted by the community, while there is a highly approved other answer: it turns the whole thing into a farce. I think ticking one's own answer should not be allowed.

Comment: This is a case of generalizing from an example.  Sometimes self-accepting is  useful.  I accepted my own answer here (http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15038/why-do-i-hear-beats-through-headphones-only-at-low-frequencies) because I thought it was right, and the question didn't attract much other attention.  My answer has one upvote, but if it had zero, it would be treated by the system as an unanswered question.  Self-accepting (I believe) stops the question from being listed with unanswered questions, so it would be useful in that context.

Comment: This is a comment to an old question, I realise, but I strongly agree with it.  There appears to be a very high correlation between questions with accepted self-answers (or, in fact, any self-answers) and questions which are essentially rhetorical tricks.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it's not a blog, it's a Q&A site. And self-answers should not be used for clarification or new thoughts; that's what the ability to edit is for. Answering a question is only for when you actually have an answer.

The purpose of having an accepted answer is to indicate how the problem posed in the original question can be solved, for the benefit of future visitors. Sometimes it is the case that you're the first/only one to discover a working solution. In these cases, you have to be able to accept your own answer, otherwise it diminishes the usefulness of the page. Admittedly, this logic applies more readily to programming questions and the like, where problems are more specific to an individual situation and it's easy for the OP to verify whether an answer works or not.

Bear in mind that when you answer your own question, no reputation is awarded, and it doesn't affect placement of the answer in the list.  So there's no side benefit to self-answering, and in cases when it happens, future visitors to the page will still see the highest voted answer.

Comment: Your explanation does not remove the ridiculousness of the resutl to the question I linked to. I edited the blog out btw. I can foresee a series of people with their own theories answering their own questions and choosing their own answer. It is not self answering that is the problem, it is the  choosing that answer as the correct one.This is not math or programming as you point out. What is to prevent this?

Comment: I guess I just don't understand why accepting one's own answer is a problem, even in the question you linked to, given that the system works the way it does. Without the placement at the top of the list, the checkmark is almost meaningless to anyone other than the asker of the question.

Comment: I guess because I look at the accepted questions to see whether the choice is reasonable, and probably I am not the only one.

Comment: @anna I believe that this kind of thing (though rare) is one of the major reasons that self-accepts don't pin to the top. Instead they have to fight it out with votes and this one is justifiable sunk. Nor do they generate any rep for the poster (neither 15 for being accepted nor 2 for accepting).

Comment: @anna I can understand your resentment to self-acceptance - in this case it really looks like an miserably failed attempt of self-promotion. However, there _are_ situations where you ask a question and later figure out the answer by yourself, which is when a self-accepted answer might also be useful for others (and get upvoted) - heck, on some SE sites I even found an answer _while typing_ the question...